# ¿Cómo importar librerías de alcance local en Angular CLI?

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Yo estoy importando librerías externas en el *"angular-cli.json"* así:

> "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
>
> "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"

etc...

Y todo trabaja muy bien, pero estas librerías, son de alcance global.

¿Cómo **incluir librerías** que se utilizarán **solo en un componente** (alcance local)?

Por ejemplo:

> "/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"

La utilizo en un solo componente, y me parece mala práctica importarla en *"angular-cli.json"*, porque quedaría con alcance global.

Comment: Todos tus componentes vas a ser parte del build the webpack, asi que no habría problemas en incluir esa libreria a nivel global

Comment: Muchas gracias nicowernli,por tu respuesta.
¿Entonces:  si tengo 10 componentes y en cada componente debo utilizar una librería diferente, tendería 10 librerías diferentes que se cargarán a nivel global.? Es decir el componente 1 cargaría 9 librerías que no necesita.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema radica en que estas cargando un plugin de jQuery que esta basado en jQuery y por lo tanto, basado en el arbol DOM.

Si cargas alguna libreria pensada para Angular 2, podras hacer eso que dices y cargarlo solo en aquellos componentes que necesites, bueno realmente, en los modulos que necesites (a traves de ngModule).

Te pongo un ejemplo para mayor claridad. Bootstrap para Angular 2:

> https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Si miras la documentacion, importas la libreria en el global para que este disponible:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Pero luego en aquellos modulos que necesites hacer uso de ella, necesitas importarlos localmente, de la siguiente manera:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [OtherComponent, ...],
  imports: [NgbModule, ...]
})
export class OtherModule {
}
```

Espero que te ayude ;)